# Problems with PySide installation

Tags: linux, qt, cmake, pyside, configure

I have python2.7.9 on my new Xubuntu installation, albeit it's 14.04. 
PySide installation stuck with Shiboken

```
Linking CXX shared library libshiboken-python2.7.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32S against `_Py_NotImplementedStruct' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [libshiboken/libshiboken-python2.7.so.1.2.2] Error 1
make[1]: *** [libshiboken/CMakeFiles/libshiboken.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
error: Error compiling shiboken
```

After some "googling" I concluded that the problem could be solved with add `--enable-shared` at `./configure` options.

Following docs tried to installed `Shiboken` in several ways, but after failed, tried to find configure in source files which I couldn't.

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output is showing that it's trying to link against a static python library, rather than a shared one - i.e. *libpython2.7.a*, rather than *libpython2.7.so*.

Thus, it's *python* that needs to be re-compiled with `--enable-shared`, not shiboken.