# Building PySide with Python 3.4

Tags: python, pyside

I need to build/install PySide for python3.4 on Debian. 
I try to build according to the instructions mentioned below:
http://pyside.readthedocs.io/en/latest/building/linux.html

I try to build PySide distribution using the Git repository.

1. $ git clone https://github.com/PySide/pyside-setup.git pyside-setup
2. $ cd pyside-setup
3. $ python2.7 setup.py bdist_wheel --qmake=/usr/bin/qmake-qt4 --version=1.2.4

at step 3, I get the following error:
[image]

In the error message it is mentioned "recompile with -fPIC". 
Could somebody please explain what this means in simple words?

How can I solve this error? (Please note that I could not manage to build two of the dependencies mentioned on the link above **qtmobility-dev libqtwebkit-dev** .

sudo apt-get install qtmobility-dev
would return "Package not found". I am not sure if this could be related to the error above.

I have managed to build PySide with python 2.7 before. It only does not build with python3.4 and I need it to be working with python3.4.

I appreciate any help,
Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Can't you just use `pip install pyside` or using environment manager like conda ?

Comment: NB: If you're trying to build pyside for python3.4 do not use python2.7 to run setup/configure scripts. In general, you must always use the executable for the *specific python installation* you want to build against. To avoid problems, always use the *full path* to the python exectutable.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks for your answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39720291/problems-with-pyside-installation. This solved the problem.